# RSA-implementation, some issues and feature

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

Hello everybody and sorry for my hard english.
I know how work rsa and all is simply for understand, but i dont understand how implement block division. some example
supposably we have alphabet where a-10,b-11...z-35. we presented our message "abcdefg" like "10111213141516", split this into blocks(for example in trhees "101""112"...for n=352),crypt this blocks and get crypted text. but what if after crypt (c = (m^e)mod n)we get some blocks with two numbers? and when we try decrypted text and split into blocks, we get other blocks maybe... 
in fine, sorry for my muddled thoughts and bad language and tell me what is true way in java for splitting text, what the length for blocks need...

Comment: Are you trying to convert the plain text message into a number that will be the input of the RSA algorithm?

Comment: yes: convert, crypt with rsa, get crypted text(353456356345635 for exmaple), convert this text and decrypt

Comment: If you have just 2 digits add a leading zero, this makes it a three digit block again.

Comment: but what if we want convert our encrypted numbers to text? and after that do decrypting? in fine what true way for splitting(m<n or m bit length < n bit length)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why implement if there is allready  JCA APIs?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html 
It  covers Java Security standards, has plenty of implemented algorithms.

See also some examples: 
http://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleRSA.html
[Single Asymmetric Key](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/AnexampleofusingRSAtoencryptasingleasymmetrickey.htm)
[RSA java example Encryption / Decryption](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/BasicRSAexample.htm)

Comment: because i am little stupid student and we have task "rsa implementation for specific p and q and choosing pair(private-public keys) in thre variants"

Comment: You may use a padding technique then if `text mod block_size !=0` then pad it with some one's or zero's.

Comment: and last question: what true way for splitting(m<n or m bit length < n bit length)?

Comment: Depends on the data type you use: A scenario might be               `String str = "12"; String pad = "000"; str=pad.substring(str.length())+str; System.out.println(str); //012`    If you work on bit level just google it

Comment: i use just text with alphabet and space, can you tell me how it depends? please example